# How to display the month as a string

Tags: php, magento-1.9, date

I have special offers section in my cart and it has a title of "August Special Offers" at this moment i have hard coded it, but i need a way of the month changing automatically so i do not have to change it myself in case i forget one month At the moment i have some up with this

```
 <h1><?php echo date('m'); ?> Exclusive offers</h1>
```

However this return "08 Exlusive offers" is there i way i can display the month in a word format instead of numerical??

Thanks if you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
<h1><?php echo date('F'); ?> Exclusive offers</h1>
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple. Can I just ask how did you know that? is there a way to find out what variable should be there to display what? or is it just experience? i will accept the answer in 11 mins when it will allow me

Comment: @AdamAllen http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you